# The “related questions” panel gone on Stackoverflow is sometimes missing

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stack-overflow

Using StackOverflow today, I *sometimes* don't see the “related questions” panel on the right side of the page, where has it gone?

However if I look at the same question later it seems to be there?

Is there a caching issue?

Comment: Do you have a link to a page without it? Working fine here.

Comment: @Nick http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4095427/how-to-write-cmakelists-for-ipad-app does not have it for me at present.

Comment: Works for me ;)

Comment: It's sometimes temperamental.

Comment: `[status-norepro]`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4095427/how-to-write-cmakelists-for-ipad-app now works for me!

Comment: I remember there was a MSO question about this, and the answer is that the algorithm is expensive, so it takes a while before the list shows up

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Correct, related costs 1s+ so it does not run that often.