# Why don't I see the "related questions" column?

Tags: bug, status-completed, related-questions

The "related questions" column has disappeared from the sidebar on SO.

[image: screenshot]

Is this a permanent change? ("Eeeek!") Or is it the first time I have witnessed this cache quirk: [The “related questions” panel gone on Stackoverflow is sometimes missing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/69397/188646)? I find that column useful from time to time, though I'm sure I could make do with the search box.

Comment: Also seems missing here on Meta.

Comment: It was there a second ago here on Meta.

Comment: Most likely a bug, stuff like this happen and fixed quickly.

Comment: Quick! To the Wheel of Blame!

Comment: If you notice, the "active" part of the question stats is missing as well. It's also missing when I look at this very question.

Comment: Y2013 bug. We all expected something.

Comment: i cann't see in this question either http://i.stack.imgur.com/cDBVQ.png

Comment: The weird part is that this doesn't seem to be a UI bug. On old questions like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/929670/find-the-element-before-and-after-a-specific-element), the related links are still present. It is just new questions that don't have them.

Comment: The API seems to be broken as well, it returns no related questions for [new questions](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/related-questions#order=desc&sort=activity&ids=14109076&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true) and behaves normally for [old questions](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/related-questions#order=desc&sort=activity&ids=929670&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true).

Comment: @Asad: I imagine that the related questions are cached and stored with the question. They likely get updated very infrequently, unless a user-generated event triggers one (such as editing, which could change the content and/or title). It would be a huge performance issue to try and generate that list every time the question loads.

Comment: On MSO looks like questions as of [8 hours ago](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/161020/182513) have the related column, but the [next question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/161023/182513) does not.

Comment: @animuson That is very likely the answer to this question. According to the info on [this page](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/related-questions#order=desc&sort=activity&ids=929670&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true), related questions lists are heavily cached. Also, user generated events do not trigger a refresh: "[the list] may not update immediately after a question has been edited."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We managed to make elastic search hard crash - it's back up and I'm taking a look at the 140gig heap dump now.  Related questions will reappear on all questions as they're accessed.

Note: as far as this question goes, [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), but I'm still looking into the root cause.

Comment: Nice, status-completed then or aren't you sure yet it's working properly?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - it's like trusting a computer after it blue screens...you just don't until you find and fix the root cause.

Comment: blue screen is like blue sky.. it's just there. ;)

Comment: Then as far as this answer goes, I'll accept it. Thanks!